# Hand soldering SOD packages

Tags: soldering

Which package is better for hand soldering with solder paste and hot air:

- SOD-323
- SOD-323F;
- SOD-323FL;

Also what is the difference between SOD-323F and SOD-323FL.

Comment: SOD-323FL has a larger pad which might help with surface tension, so easier for manual processes.

Comment: Note that the F variant with its flat leads is more difficult to solder with solder wire. Not a concern to you as you're using paste, but may be good to know.